# How can I fetch the current encrypted url Base64

Tags: javascript, html, url, base64

I want to extract the current url with decoding Base64,  Or it works correctly without decoding it

My encoder url is:

```
www.site.com/search?cT1pZnJhbWUmb3E9aWZyYW1lJmFxcz1jaHJvbWUuLjY5aTU3ajY5aTU5ajY5aTY1bDNqNjlpNjBzMJV
```

```html
<p id="lin"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("lin").innerHTML =
"url: " + window.location.href;
</script>
```

It must be decrypted

```
url:https://www.google.com/search?q=iframe&oq=iframe&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i65l3j69i60l3.1478248423j0j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<p id="lin"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("lin").innerHTML =
"url: " + window.location.hostname + "?" + (atob( window.location.search.split('&')[1]));
</script>
```

[example](https://codepen.io/dkmd/pen/eYJzdLz?&cT1pZnJhbWUmb3E9aWZyYW1lJmFxcz1jaHJvbWUuLjY5aTU3ajY5aTU5ajY5aTY1bDNqNjlpNjBzMJV)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)

```js
let url = "www.site.com/search?cT1pZnJhbWUmb3E9aWZyYW1lJmFxcz1jaHJvbWUuLjY5aTU3ajY5aTU5ajY5aTY1bDNqNjlpNjBzMJV";

let parts = url.split("?");

document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = parts[0] + "?" + atob(parts[1]);
```

```html
<p></p>
```